# How to itertate into pandas dataframe column and delete specific row?

Tags: python, pandas

This is my csv file:

```
A  B  C  D
0  1  5  5
1  0  3  0
0  0  0  0
2  1  3  4
```

I want it check The B column if I foud 0 I delete all the row so this what I need as output:

```
A  B  C  D
0  1  5  5
2  1  3  4
```

I tried this code :

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('Book1.csv', sep=',', error_bad_lines=False, dtype='unicode')
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['B'] == 0:
        df.drop(row,index=False)
df.to_csv('hello.csv')
```

It return for me :

```
   A  B  C  D
0  0  1  5  5
1  1  0  3  0
2  0  0  0  0
3  2  1  3  4
```

It did not delete any thing I don't know where is the problem
Any help please !

Comment: You didn't drop `inplace` but anyway, you shouldn't be iterating. `df = df[df['B'] != 0]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select rows from a DataFrame based on values in a column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check which rows in `B` are not equal to `1`, and perform [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with the result:

```
df[df.B.ne(0)]

   A  B  C  D
0  0  1  5  5
3  2  1  3  4
```

---

Note that in your approach, in order to drop a given row, you need to specify the index, so you should be doing something like:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['B'] == 0:
        df.drop(index, inplace=True)
df.to_csv('hello.csv')
```

Also don't forget to reassign the result after dropping a row. This can be done setting `inplace` to `True` or reassigning back to `df`.